# Is Distinguished name always present for Active Directory objects?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

As far as I know, distinguished name is a must for an Active Directory object.
No object exists in Active Directory without a distinguished name.
Can there be a possibility that an Active Directory object (example an AD user) does not have a distinguished name ?

Comment: Everything in any LDAP directory has a distinguished name. You've said that yourself. I don't understand why you are even asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

A Directory is a TREE of objects and somewhere the distinguished Name is the way to join each object in the tree. So **YES** every object will always have a distinguished name because **the distinguished name is the path** to the object in the tree.

If you move an object in the Directory the Distinguiched Name of the object will change to reflect the new path.

An Object without Distinguished Name (found in the database when corrupted) will be stored in the lostandfound container and so will have a distinguished name so **it's not possible to have an object in a directory without distinguished name**.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that although a distinguished name always exists for an object, it is not stored on the object statically. What is stored is the object's RDN, i.e. Relative Distinguished Name and I believe the system actually dynamically generates the DN of an object by concatenating the RDNs of the object and all its parent objects up until the root of the object.